# Angular 15 - View not updating after BehaviorSubject emmits change

Tags: html, angular, view, observable

I have a service with a BehaviourSubject which I can subscribe to from any component:

```
// getter in service
public get myObs$(): Observable<any> {
  return this._myBhvSub$.asObservable()
}
```

Then in the component I do

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myService.myObs$.subscribe(res => {
    this.myVar = res
    console.log("My Var", this.myVar)
  })
}
```

**concole.log()** shows the data !! **myVar** is getting its value correctly !!

Finally HTML

```
<div>{{myVar.someKey}}</div>
```

This view just won't show the data

I also tested hardcoding MyVar like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myService.myObs$.subscribe(res => {
    this.myVar = {someKey: "Hello World"}
    console.log("My Var", this.myVar)
  })
}
```

...and this works just fine

## **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the console.log you mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this:

```
 <div>{{(myService.myObs$ | async).someKey}}</div>
```

N.B : make myService public

if async pipe work it mean you have onPush detection in your component or parent component